# How to secure the default page of Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, security-constraint

I want to make the default page of my Tomcat7 server private, i. e. accessible only after `.htaccess` password has been entered.

I mean this page:

[image: Tomcat default page]

For that purpose, I added:

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

to `tomcat-users.xml`.

Then I added:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/references/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Application</realm-name>
</login-config>

<!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
<security-role>
    <description>
    The role that is required to log in to the Manager Application
    </description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

to `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

But when I open the default page, htaccess dialog box still doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See: [Specifying an Authentication Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbn/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `<url-pattern>`, it is pointing to `/references/*` (which doesn't exist in the ROOT folder)
The typical Tomcat setup the welcome page is in the root folder so the `<url-pattern>` should be pointing to `/*`.